# Correct definition of locally uniform convergence

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, sequence-of-function

We have a sequence of complex functions $f_n\colon D \subseteq \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ where $D$ is a generic set.

What is the correct definition of locally uniform convergence of the sequence $(f_n)$ to the function $f\colon D \to \mathbb{C}$ in the set $D$?

I have found (as possible definition) the following ones:

1. $\forall \,z \in D \quad \exists \,B_r(z)=\{w \in \mathbb{C} \mid |w-z|<r\} \mid (f_n)$ uniformly converges to $f$ on $B_r(z) \cap D$;
2. $\forall \,K \subseteq D \mid K$ is compact, we have that $(f_n)$ uniformly converges to $f$ on $K$;
3. For every closed disk $B$ contained in $D$ we have that $(f_n)$ uniformly converges to $f$ on $B$.

I have found that the three definitions are equivalent if $D$ is an open set. Is this true?

Thank you!

Comment: One more definition https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Locally_Uniform_Convergence

Comment: I would take $2$ in general; since open balls finitely exhaust compacts (any compact is contained in a finite union of open balls centered at points on the compact), $2$ and $1$ are easily seen as equivalent, while for the equivalence with $3$ you need an open set indeed since $3$ tells you nothing about points that are not in the interior of $D$ (or on the boundary of the interior of $D$)

Comment: I can see that 1 implies 2, but I think that we need that D is an open set for the reverse implication (namely that 2 implies 1).